# Get a price of auto renewable subscription via App Store Connect API

Tags: app-store-connect

How can I get current or past price of a subscription via App Store Connect API? I managed to get price points but these are all available prices rather than a current price.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is probably not helpful almost a year later, but I was having this same issue today. So in order to access the current price use the following URL:

```
https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/subscriptions/{idOfSubscription}/prices?filter[territory]=USA&include=subscriptionPricePoint
```

The query params help limit the response size and get the associate price tier for a subscription IN a territory. A subscription can have a different price tier in different territories.

In the response, look for the subscriptionPrices item with the attribute preserved = true.  This is your current price info.  In the item look in the relationships -> subscriptionPricePoint -> data -> id.  That is your current price tier for the territory.

```
{
        "type": "subscriptionPrices",
        "id": "someCoolPriceId",
        "attributes": {
            "startDate": null,
            "preserved": false
        },
        "relationships": {
            "subscriptionPricePoint": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "subscriptionPricePoints",
                    "id": "pricePointId"
                }
            }
        },
```

Use the id to match to the subscriptionPricePoints in the "included" array.  That will contain the actual price.

```
 "included": [
    {
        "type": "subscriptionPricePoints",
        "id": "pricePointId",
        "attributes": {
            "customerPrice": "6.99",
            "proceeds": "5.94",
            "proceedsYear2": "5.94"
        },
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I guess it will always return the current price. So if somebody subscribed on a cheaper plan there still now ways of knowing how much they are charged through this api, right?

Comment: @MaciejCaputa If the user is using an introductory or promotional offer, it will be in the Transaction (aka receipt) object.  See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/jwsrenewalinfodecodedpayload

Comment: I don't see it there. Can you send me a link to a section describing a price of with wich a subscription renews? Thank you in advance

Comment: Once you decode the signed transaction its the offerType property.  If the offerType is a 2 or 3 use the offerIdentifier property for more info regarding details of the subscription offer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/offertype

Comment: @dom Where did you read about startDate = null and preserved = true being the current/latest price?

Comment: @AlexanderSelling  I have amended why answer to reflect, preserved should = false. Mistake on my end the preserved attribute is when a price change occurs but choose to preserve pricing for existing subscribers.